# list of custom labels. Or list of pages with labels?

Tags: visualforce, customlabel

I'm tasked with using customlabels to translate a portal, but i'm getting duplicates. So, is there a way to find a list of visualforce pages? Then maybe with pagereference, i can get to labels. Or the other way around, a list of labels, then find where they are used. The only workaround is copying all of them to excel, and find duplicates there. But i will still have to find the page where a label is used, with search in code, in the console. And its pain to update.

edit: so far, i can only find specific labels, like this
https://blog.moothien.me/2017/02/retrieve-salesforce-label-dynamically.html

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get list of Visualforce Pages by having query

```
   SELECT Id, Name FROM ApexPage
```

You can get list of labels by running Tooling Api query

```
   Select Id FROM ExternalString
```

Comment: sorry for the late response. Yes with apexpage i think i can find the labels:

SELECT Id, Name, namespaceprefix, Masterlabel, Description, Markup FROM ApexPage

Then maybe some regular expressions, i can map all the labels used. Will test when possible. Thanks